# BigQuery Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got ")"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to get with list of items not matched in my table. I am able to do this in SQL Server but BQ is throwing error.

```
SELECT
  ID
FROM
  (VALUES ('helloworld')) --> Here is the error
AS v(ID) except
SELECT
  ID
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
```

I tried to change the query mode to LegacySQL , still it didn't work. Anyidea whatsgoing on in here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT ID
FROM (SELECT 'helloworld' as ID) v
EXCEPT DISTINCT
-------^ required in BQ
SELECT ID
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

I would just use `NOT EXISTS` or something similar but this should also work.

Comment: Thanks v much, so I have multiple values I can just use `(SELECT ('helloworld'),('qwerty') as Id)`